# Missing namespace/assembly errors in T4 files

Tags: .net, namespaces, t4

I am having trouble in using [this microsoft's translator api code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx) inside a T4 file.

I can't get over the

> type or namespace does not exist in 'System' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference ?)

error messages in using System.ServiceModel in T4 files.

I have several namespaces not being recognized. For example, System.ServiceModel.

I did add:

- The assembly as a reference to the project.
- As well as both assembly
  and namespace directives to the T4 file.

To no avail.

What else can be done ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T4 template only imports the System.ServiceModel namespace it does not reference the System.ServiceModel assembly. It is missing the assembly directive.

```
<#@ assembly name="System.ServiceModel" #>
```

Comment: Very weird, although this is missing in my screenshot, I did add this (as mentioned in the post). In any case, you are right, this removes the error message from the list. Will try this for all the others. Thanks.